# Как достать исходный код текущей страницы из CppWebBrowser?

Tags: c++builder, web-apps, c++

Есть компонент `CppWebBrowser`. Как достать из него исходный код текущей страницы?

Comment: Разве никто не сталкивался с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Решил ответить на свой старый вопрос :)*

Вобщем, никакое извращение с `browserInstance->Document` не даст желательного результата, полностью пройти путь к исходному коду незаметно для пользователя не получится. Лучший выход — `get/post`-запросы к сайту. Отправить их легко *(но нестабильно)* можно отправить с помощью компонента `IdHTTP` (`Indy Client`), или же писать свой алгоритм установления свяи и отправки.

Иногда "кажется", что невозможно получить страницу запросом, например на `cgi`-странице. Но, как показал личный опыт, всё возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Опираясь на вот этот вот [пример,](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=690434) готов предположить, что необходимо манипулировать с полем `browserInstance->Document`.

Как мне кажется это поле является сущностью какого-нибудь класса типа `HTMLDocument`, или, может быть моделирует схожий интерфейс. *Дальше вытащить сорцы страницы должно быть достаточно тривиально.*

---

Не уверен, что это все абсолютно правильно, т.к нет ни `CppBuilder`, ни документации по `CppWebBrowser` под рукой, но думаю, что мыслю я в правильном направлении.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ

впринцыпе, я так и думал, но проблема в том, что __browserInstance->Document__ возвращает переменную класса ___di_ispatch__ — а как её перевести в обычную строку - не известно. Прогуглил - нет результата